# PHP MySQL Select Statement Error

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm new to MySQL and PHP and am having trouble with this code. Please do tell me where I am going wrong:

Here's the code:

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

$num1  = '1';
$num2  = '2';

// Get all the data from the  table

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num1 = '$num1' AND num2 = '$num2'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) or die("No rows returned by query");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo $row["num1"];
echo '</br>';
echo $row["num2"];
echo '</br>';
}

?>
```

If I change

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num1 = '$num1' AND num2 = '$num2'");
```

to

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num1 > '$num1' AND num2 > '$num2'");
```

it works. It doesn't work with the equal sign although there are records that should be printed out.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show the schema and (relevant) content of your `table1` table.

Comment: Is there an error or just no result? If there is an error, show us the error message please

Comment: What are the values of the returned rows if you change the query?

Comment: I don't believe the quotes are your problem, unless I'm missing something? For instance I can run `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id = '81837' AND customer_id = '13';` in a database where both those fields are `INT`s and it works fine. Can you provide you SCHEMA and any error messages/returned values?

Comment: @DKSan If I change the equal sign to greater than I get the results. There are only 5 records now, just numbers between 1 and 10 in all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is you are fetching the results twice, 
so remove the fetch statement outside the while loop**($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) or die("No rows returned by query");)** and it should work.
Please update if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try again

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num1 = $num1 AND num2 = $num2
```

Comment: in any database? or I need to turn on some option?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing numbers,try using them without quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num1=$num1 AND num2=$num2
```

Comment: The table's design is as below:

serial | type: int| length - 4| Decimals 0|Primary Key| Auto increment
num1|  type: int| length - 4| Decimals 0| Allow null
num2|  type: int| length - 4| Decimals 0| Allow null
num3 |  type: int| length - 4| Decimals 0| Allow null